# Genshi TemplateSyntaxError on python block where it should work

Tags: python, syntax-error, codeblocks, genshi

```
<?python class += 1 ?>
```

One really simple line of code which definitely should work, but still it gives me this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: invalid syntax (file.html, line 22)
```

I shorted the filepath for readability, but that's the exact error. I'm definitely sure it should work, as I've used

```
<?python
    i += 1
?>
```

In another file, and it worked just fine there. Almost exact same structure; a table and a py:for loop. Tried everything, but can't get it to work! Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` is a Python keyword. You can't name a variable that.

Comment: Good point, thanks for that anyway. Oh crap;
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'